# How to pause/resume video in Exoplayer?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am using **[Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)** for playing video

**`Code For Playing Video`**

---

```
private PlayerView videoView;
SimpleExoPlayer player;
```

---

```
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector());
    videoView.setPlayer(player);
    player.prepare(buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(_videoUrl)));
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //i want to pause video
            //next time i want to resume
            return false;
        }
    });
```

---

**`XML CODE`**

---

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    //i don't want to use controls to i am setting false
    app:use_controller="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I cant find any usefull docs to pause and resume video

my requirement is to **`pause/resume`** video when touch on VideoView any one now how to do it ?

**`Dependency`**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.7.3'
```

Comment: Use setPlayWhenReady() - false to pause, true - to resume

Comment: @Gautam thank you its working

Comment: @Gautam can you provide answer ? i am using code `videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                player.setPlayWhenReady(!player.getPlayWhenReady());
                return false;
            }
        });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`For Play Video`**

```
private void playPlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
}
```

**`For Pause Video`**

```
private void pausePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}
```

**`From Specific Position`**

```
private void seekTo(long positionInMS) {
    if (player != null) {
        player.seekTo(positionInMS);
    }
}
```

**`Relase Player`**

```
private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code or logic for pausing video ? i cant find in provided code ...can you explain more ?

Comment: private voide playPlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
}

private voide pausePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}

private void seekTo(long positionInMS) {
    if (player != null) {
        player.seekTo(positionInMS);
    }
}

private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
    }
}